# How to create actions on google using Spring Boot & Java Library

Tags: java, spring-boot, actions-on-google

I am trying to create actions on google using Spring Boot & Dialogflow. In which I was trying to use the available java library https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java

But couldn't understand how should I implement these annotations in my Spring Boot Application. Eg: @ForIntent

I have tried the boilerplate code with App Engine entry point
https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-boilerplate-java
I was able to run this code, but couldn't understand its implementation in Spring boot Application.

In Spring Boot:
We use @RestController in the application to map the requests

But with actions on google there would be only one request link, we can provide as Fulfillment webhook. So where should I use the @ForIntent in my code to identify the Intent and change Request body & Response body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually did this at one point, and based it off of the [Silly Name Maker](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-silly-name-maker-webhook-java) sample. I based it on one of the Spring Boot canonical samples, so I'm not going to guarantee this is 'optimal', but it's a pretty clean implementation.

You can keep the `SillyNameMakerApp` the same, unmodified. Instead of the ActionsServlet, you can create a Spring Boot wrapper like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldApplication {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SillyNameMakerApp.class);
    private final App actionsApp = new SillyNameMakerApp();

    @Value("${TARGET:World}")
    String message;

    @RestController
    class HelloworldController {
        @GetMapping("/")
        String serveAck() {
            return "App is listening but requires valid POST request to respond with Action response.";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
        String serveAction(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
            try {
                return actionsApp.handleRequest(body, headers).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                return handleError(e);
            }
        }

        private String handleError(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Error in App.handleRequest ", e);
            return "Error handling the intent - " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of how Action on Google works, but having a look at it on a higher level, in the sample app, the requests are handled through ActionServlet

https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-boilerplate-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/ActionsServlet.java

The ActionServlet.java class, extends the plain old java servlet called as HttpServlet, if you have a look inside the doPost() method:

```
private final App actionsApp = new MyActionsApp(); ----> Bullet Point - 1

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    String body = req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    LOG.info("doPost, body = {}", body);

    try {
      String jsonResponse = actionsApp.handleRequest(body, getHeadersMap(req)).get(); ----> Bullet Point - 2
      LOG.info("Generated json = {}", jsonResponse);
      res.setContentType("application/json");
      writeResponse(res, jsonResponse);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      handleError(res, e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      handleError(res, e);
    }
  }
```

So your question is how to do the same in Spring Boot. Spring uses a DispatcherServlet to map the incoming requests to the controllers, so internally spring uses the similar mechanims to map incoming requests. To answer you question, in Spring Boot terminology, you want to do something like below:

```
@RestController("/action")
public class ActionController{

    @Autowired
    private App actionsApp;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void handleActions(){
       // Similar method call like Bullet Point 2
       // I assume handleRequest() method will call the @ForIntent method here ?? No idea
       actionsApp.handleRequest(.....);
    }
}
```

And configure the `MyActionsApp.java` like below:

```
 @Service
public class MyActionsApp extends DialogflowApp {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyActionsApp.class);

  @ForIntent("Default Welcome Intent")
  public ActionResponse welcome(ActionRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info("Welcome intent start.");
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = getResponseBuilder(request);
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources");
    User user = request.getUser();

    if (user != null && user.getLastSeen() != null) {
      responseBuilder.add(rb.getString("welcome_back"));
    } else {
      responseBuilder.add(rb.getString("welcome"));
    }

    LOGGER.info("Welcome intent end.");
    return responseBuilder.build();
  }

  @ForIntent("bye")
  public ActionResponse bye(ActionRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info("Bye intent start.");
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = getResponseBuilder(request);
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources");

    responseBuilder.add(rb.getString("bye")).endConversation();
    LOGGER.info("Bye intent end.");
    return responseBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

PS: I am assuming that actionsApp.handleRequest(..) method will some how call the @ForIntent based on some other configuration. But if you want to port the ActionServlet implementation to SpringBoot, this would be the way to do that.

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation. Yes this is the right way.